# PnP.PowerShell - "Host not reachable" error

Tags: powershell, sharepoint

Getting "Host Not Reachable" error when trying to connect to SharePoint site using Connect-PnPOnline command with the latest version of PnP PoerShell (v2.3).  The error never occured and still does not occur when using the previous 2.2 version of PnP PowerShell.

This is the full command:

```
Connect-PnPOnline -Url $SiteUrl -ClientId $Client_Id -ClientSecret $Client_Secret -Verbose -ErrorAction stop
```

Tried reverting to previous version of PnP PowerShell and it connects no problem.  As soon as PnP PowerShell is upgraded to the latest 2.3 version the error returns.